# How can I rotate two objects at the same time?

Tags: scene

Is it possible to rotate two or more models at the same time within Blender?

[image: example]

Comment: Jachmy,i put all questions on my head :) and these are just questions I don't know and not tested (cant find on google)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add a new empty, select the objects, and then select the empty, Right-click and click on parent > parent to empty. Then to rotate, scale, move, etc. all the objects, just select the empty and rotate, move, scale, etc. it.

Comment: You Are Best Man